# Running "python setup.py install" second time fails with [WinError 32] error message

Tags: python, setup.py

Trying to install several well-established Python modules from the source using "python setup.py install" command on Windows running Python 3.11. Everything works during the first run, no error messages. However, when running the same command second time (for no practical reason, just trying to make sure that my client will not be able to crash anything if the command is run second time inadvertently), I am getting the following error message:

```
Processing PyYAML-6.0-py3.11-win-amd64.egg
Removing c:\users\wdagutilityaccount\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages\PyYAML-6.0-py3.11-win-amd64.egg
error: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\wdagutilityaccount\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python311\\lib\\site-packages\\PyYAML-6.0-py3.11-win-amd64.egg'
```

Important:

1. A specific module (PyYAML) is not important here, I get the same message with other modules like graphviz for instance, so the issue is not caused by the module being installed.
2. The file in question (PyYAML-6.0-py3.11-win-amd64.egg) is actually not locked by any other process right after the script terminates, I can delete it manually later, so either the file lock is transient during the script execution, or something else is causing this error.
3. Furthermore, if I simply delete this file prior to running the second time (without uninstalling anything else), the second run completes without any error messages.
4. I tried "python setup.exe install --force", but it did not help.
5. No, I can't install using any other higher-level alternatives like "pip3 install pyyaml" or from the wheel file - the requirement is that I install from a local copy of the source.

So, hence the questions:

1. What is a **reliable way to install from the source unlimited number of times?**
2. I would be fine with the **second run terminating with something like "already installed, nothing to do here, all good" type of message**, is there any way to do that?

Comment: "What is a reliable way to install from the source unlimited number of times?" - I can't understand - exactly what do you expect to happen if you try this? If it's already installed, are you expecting more files to be put into more places, or other work to be done? What, specifically?

Comment: I expect one of the two things: either the script should say "module already installed, there is nothing to do here, all is good" or "module already installed, but I will reinstall it, overwriting existing files". In either case the result (error code) should be "success". What I DON'T expect (and what I actually get) is the script first trying to install something over already installed files and then failing with an error message. And no, there is no practical purpose of installing multiple times - this is simply an attempt to make the installation fool-proof.

Comment: Based on what I can make out of the error message, it looks to me like there was just some kind of glitch that resulted in a file lock not being released, so that Windows complains about cleanup trying to delete the file for a reinstall.